# what is the difference between (div#container) and (#container) in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

It's well known that the id should be unique in html tags, so it can be referenced directly using:

```
#container
```

However I noticed that some developer will prefix it with the tag name like this:

```
div#container
```

Now is there a difference? Is it related to performance? Or is it best practice conventions? Or for easy code readability?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `div#container` has higher priority than `#container`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I asked this question with a wrong assumptions as follow:

1. There will be only one HTM page, hence:
2. There should be only one ID (container)
3. There will be an internal CSS block for such page

Based on the above wrong assumptions,  it's needless to include the tag name.

However,  the correct assumptions should be:

1. You have a website with multiple pages
2. Although id(container) is unique in every page, however it might be assigned to different elements, e.g. `div id="conainer"` in one page. And `p id="container"` in another page
3. most probably there is an external css file or is file that serves all these pages.

Its based on those assumptions the benefit of being more specific prefixing the tag name will prevent abnormal behavior

This is almost the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22982228/1679011) of laaposto

Answer (score 4):

`div#container` will ensure you only select the element if it is a `div`. Without the type selector, any element with that ID will be targeted. The type selector also adds [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity), but that's a minor thing.

Assuming you're following best practices and making sure your IDs are unique per page, you generally don't need to overqualify your ID selectors; having `#container` should be enough. But if you have a very good reason to distinguish the element type, there are no rules preventing you from doing that (although frankly, given the whole nature of IDs, I don't see why the same ID should ever be assigned to different types of elements altogether).

Answer (score 3):

The basic difference is that with `div#container` you may not target an element although there is an element with `id=container`. For example if you have

`<div id="container"></div>`

then both will point the same element. But if you have

`<p id="container"></p>`

Then only the selector `#container` will target it. The selector `div#container` will not

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `div#container` and `#container` is that

`#container` will only apply to **element** that has `id="container"`

While,

`div#container` will only apply to **DIV** that has an `id="container"`

Although you it is considered best practice to only use an id once. And if you need to use certain CSS again, might as well use class.

Answer (score 1):

In html you may have a lot of other elements, such as span, table, etc, which may have the same id, for example "container". So this code:

```
#container: {....}
```

is a reference to all of them.

But when you write this:

```
div#container: {...}
```

You refer in a specific subcategory of those items. Also you may have a lot of divs. By this reference above, you target in a specific subcategory of divs elements.