# Difference between element#id-name and #id-name in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

In CSS what is is the difference between element#id-name and #id-name for the same element.Since id's are unique, then why are there the two forms given before used. For eg: Difference between div#para and #para.

Comment: Side note: since an ID is intended to be unique through the whole DOM, there must be no difference between these two selectors.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981989/what-is-the-difference-between-divcontainer-and-container-in-css and many, many others.

Answer (score 3):

`element#id-name` is "stronger" than `#id-name` and if there are multiple reference to one element, the stronger is the one applied to the element

see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kJrCT/

Comment: By "stronger" ekan means "more specific".

Answer (score 3):

`div#para` only applies to divs with id "para", while `#para` applies to all element types with that id.  Consider the fact that on another page you could have a span with id "para".  You could use `div#para` to style only the div, `span#para` to style only the span, and `#para` to apply css styling to all #para elements throughout the website.

There are a number of reasons you might like to use the same id for different elements depending on the page being viewed.  Also, being more or less specific affects the priority of the style being applied.

Answer (score 0):

**In your case**, Both are exactly the same. They refer to the same element.

Its just for readabilty, so that the person looking @ the css can know which element has the id "para".

**But Generally** this is useful when you apply the same[generic] class to many elements at the same time, and you want to refer to only one specific element, having that class.

Eg:

```
.pull-left{
   float:left;
}
```

// This applies to all the elements with this class

This can be given to a 'p' or a 'div' or any element. but if you want to refer to a **div** with the class **pull-left**, then you can use

```
div.pull-left   /// refers only to the <div>'s having class pull-left
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same css on multiple pages and if you use the same id-name but with different element you can use some common rules.

Example:

```
#title{
    color: red;
}

h2#title{
    font-size: 16pt;
}

h1#title{
    font-size: 22pt;
}
```

So, your h1 with title id-name will be red and with size 22pt and your h2 with id-name (on other page) will be red too but with 16pt size.